# making a tag target of event, not img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is probably javascript 101 but I can't figure out a solution to this. Consider the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvHU9/)

My js sets the click event on the a tag using the class `.show-modal`

and yet my console log shows that the event target was actually the img tag.  I need the event target to be the a tag for various reasons.

Two things about this that present a challenge for me:

1. The only way I've been successful in getting the event target to be the a tag is to separate the img tag outside of it (i.e. make it a sibling of the a tag, not a child anymore) and then set the a tag position: absolute, give it dimensions and position over the img.  I think this approach has got to be the least desirable but how else can I achieve my goal?
2. What really confuses me is how can the event target be different from the element upon which I attached the click event?  Shouldn't they be the same?  If they should be the same, how could my function be called if the element receiving the click event is NOT the one I attached my click event to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event target is the element which triggered the event, not necessarily the element which the handler is attached to.

When you click on the image, the event propagates up the DOM tree, triggering the `click` handler bound to the `anchor`.

If you need the `anchor`, you can use `this`.

Comment: I knew it had to do with event propagation, i just wasn't completely sure on how it worked out.  I don't think I can use "this" since I need to determine which a tag was clicked and then find a particular data attribute attached to it.

Comment: @max7: I'm pretty sure you can use `this`, it wouldn't be the target, but it would certainly be the `anchor` which corresponds to the clicked `img`. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvHU9/7/)

Comment: Thanks very much for the excellent fiddle!  So basically, because the a tag where I bound my click handler intercepts the event in the bubbling phase, that allows me to use "this" and get the proper data attrs on the a tag ... did I get that right?

Answer (score 7):

Use

`e.currentTarget` -- Gives the element to which event is bound. (Can use **this**  as well)

`e.target`        -- Gives the element that triggered the event.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FvHU9/5/)**

The issue here is your image almost entirely occupies the anchor. So the `anchor` tag will never be the `e.target` ..

Check out a example where the heights are different.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FvHU9/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` instead of target: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FvHU9/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-modal').on('click',function(e){
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think I can use "this" since I need to find the actual a tag with the click handler attached to it so that I can then find a specific data attribute attached to it.

Comment: @max7: `this` would be the element the click handler is attached to

Answer (score 1):

The event is triggered on an `img` tag, but the listener's context is a tag with the `show-modal` class, therefore the callbacks context will be where the listener was attached:

```
$('.show-modal').on('click', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log($(this));//the .show-modal tag
});
```

That's all. If ever you find yourself delegating the event, and you want to check if the element clicked is the child of some element with ID x, or class Y:

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(e)
{//this catches all clicks on all imgs in your page
    console($(this) === $(document));//true
    console.log(e.target);//img tag
    if ($(e.target).closest('.show-modal'))
    {
        console.log('yes, clicked image is child of .show-modal element'):
    }
});
```